# Finding the inner product of two 3D tensors in Keras custom layer

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

In my Keras custom layer, I have to find the inner product of two 3D tensors. For example , x=(?,80,150,12) is the input to the layer and the inner product have to be with all the 4 slices of kernel (80,150,12,4), 4 being the slicing dimension. I am trying to do it with K.dot but I am getting dimension mismatch error. The code snippet is

```
kernel1_unpacked = tf.unstack(self.kernel1,axis=3)                
 all_probs = []

 for t in kernel1_unpacked:
     t=K.permute_dimensions(t,[2,0,1])
     B3=K.sum(K.dot(x,t),[1,2,3])
     B3=K.expand_dims(B3,1)
     print(B3)
     all_probs.append(B3)

 B4=tf.concat(all_probs[:],axis=1)

 print(B4)
```

the output should have dimension (?,4).